# addDomlistener on dynamically loaded google map

Tags: google-maps-api-3, click, load, addeventlistener

I have a button that toggles a chart on the page I'm creating. First I created it using the [google maps api example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls), but then I found out there is no way to position it in a custom location except the predefined places, so I recreated it with html/css in my grid.

It works, however when I'm using `.load()` to replace the map canvas and chart with a new set, the if-else statement is ignored and with one mouse click the console log writes: click2, click. The map is not resized and the chart just jumps in and out. Also the classes I'm adding and removing are stay intact.

```
var chartbtn = document.getElementById('chart-id');
google.maps.event.addDomListener(chartbtn, 'click', function(event) {

if( $(chartbtn).hasClass('open') ) {
    $('.plot').animate({"bottom" : "-190px"}, 200);
    $('#map_canvas').height( winHeight - 40 + 'px');
    $(chartbtn).removeClass('open').addClass('closed');

    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    console.info('click');

} else {

    $('.plot').animate({"bottom" : "0px"}, 200);
    $('#map_canvas').height( winHeight - 230 + 'px');
    $(chartbtn).removeClass('closed').addClass('open');

    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    var newbounds = map.getBounds(); 
    map.fitBounds(newbounds);
    console.info('click2');
}
});
```

How come that everything works with the newly loaded map (xml data, markers, infowindows etc.) but not this click function?